# Build docker image from Dockerfile using Bazel

Tags: docker, bazel

I have a fairly simple `Dockerfile` and now would like to build a docker image using [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker).
Trying to use [`container_image`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image-1), it seems like I cannot use the `Dockerfile` as input. Is there any way to build with a `Dockerfile`?

Comment: What is "container_image"?

Comment: The Bazel rule to build hermetic containers AFAIK

Answer (score 5):

Update: There is now a rule called `dockerfile_image`. Read here for more details: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/contrib/dockerfile_build.bzl#L15

Answer (score 2):

I think it's by design not allowed due to `non-hermetic` nature of `Dockerfile`. We can `RUN` any command in `Dockerfile`, including the ones non-hermetic (can't always been reproduced)

Further discussion here:

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/173
- https://blog.bazel.build/2015/07/28/docker_build.html